# IOS IPhone label moving when screen scrolled

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview, cells

I appreciate that this is probably something people will need code samples to properly answer but unfortunately I don't have them to hand at the moment so I'm asking for peoples experiences and whether they've seen anything like this before.

I have a `view` with a UITableView in it, there are a bunch of cells and on this particular view if I scroll the screen down then the label that's in the last cell superimposes itself on top of the label in the first cell.

It only happens on this one view where the first and last cells appear or don't appear in the `UITableView` depending on whether certain values are in a JSON feed.

If both cells are in the `UITableView` then when you scroll,  the label of the bottom one appears on top of the top one. The bottom cell's label is still in place, as is the top one - just with the bottom one on top of it!

So, has anyone seen anything like this and if so is there's an obvious thing I'm doing wrong that this type of occurrence is a symptom of?

Comment: There will be a problem in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you are probably adding a label as a subview every time, even when a cell has been dequeued. That is the answer to ~80% of the UITableView questions on SO.

Comment: You may well be right, will check and see. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this is the problem alright, question now though is how do I check for the cell being dequeued or not.

Comment: If you include your cellForRowAtIndexPath method you will get some suggestions, I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

How to look for the cell being dequeued?

Check out `[UITableViewCell prepareForReuse]` and that's where you can remove previously inserted subview(s) before adding new ones.

Here's the Apple documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse